# Python numbers to string in xml creation

Tags: xml, python-2.7

As the name states I am trying to create an XML sheet using python to store data for the code I am working with. My issue comes when I try to squeeze my numbers into the XML as string data. Here is what I have:

```
print "pyClicker2.0 - Manual Input Mode\nPlease set two coordinate pairs..."
x1 = raw_input("What is x1: ")
y1 = raw_input("What is y1: ")
x2 = raw_input("what is x2: ")
y2 = raw_input("what is y2: ")

#pyClickerXML - XML Out
root = Element("coordinates")
tree = ElementTree(root)
x1Elm = Element("x1")
y1Elm = Element("y1")
x2Elm = Element("x2")
y2Elm = Element("y2")

x1Elm.text = x1.tostring()
y1Elm.text = y1.tostring()
x2Elm.text = x2.tostring()
y2Elm.text = y2.tostring()

tree.write(open("c:\\users\namehere\Desktop\coord_man.xml", "wt"))
```

Here is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
man()
File "C:/Users/Zilvarael/Desktop/Folder of CodeMonkey/piSrc/pyclickerXML.py", line 36,    in man
x1Elm.text = x1.tostring()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tostring'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing this:

```
x1 = raw_input("What is x1: ")
...
x1Elm.text = x1.tostring()
```

The [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) function already returns a string, so you shouldn't need to convert it.

Comment: That generates the sheet but none of the coordinate data is present just the root element.

Comment: For all wondering, I was missing the root.append(varName) attribute for each xy value! -- thanks Bill!